# Translating temperature (Fahrenheit and Celsius) in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, conditional-statements, temperature

So I have this simple program which the user can use to tell where they're from and where they're currently at (Only using the USA and the UK for this). I would like the program to translate the temperature from the usual temperature scale in the country the user is currently in, to the usual temperature scale to the country from which they come from. I'm struggling quite a bit to come up with a reasonable solution for this so I'm open for any suggestions, thanks.

Here's my code so far:

```
location = input("Where are you from?\n")
uk = ("the UK")
us = ("the USA")
if location == uk:
print("You are from the UK.\n")
elif location == us:
print("You are from the USA.\n")
else:
print("Sadly, I cannot help you.\n")
locationNow = input("Where are you currently at?\n")
if locationNow == uk:
print("You are currently in the UK.\n")
elif locationNow == us:
print("You are currently in the US.\n")
else:
print("Sadly I cannot help you.\n")
temp = input("What is the temperature for tomorrow?\n")
```

Comment: What _suggestions_ are you looking for? What exactly are you struggeling with?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To expand on the answer provided by FanMan, you can do something like this:

```
def c2f():
    C_to_F = (temp × 9/5) + 32
    return(C_to_F)

def f2c():
    F_to_C = (temp - 32) × 5/9
    return(F_to_C)


temp = input("What is the temperature for tomorrow?\n")

if locationNow == uk & location == us:
    print('The temperature will be ' + str(temp) + 'C or ' + str(c2f(temp)) + 'F')
elif locationNow == us & location == uk:
    print('The temperature will be ' + str(temp) + 'F or ' + str(f2c(temp)) + 'C')
elif locationNow == us & location == us:
    print('The temperature will be ' + str(temp) + 'F')
else:
    print('The temperature will be ' + str(temp) + 'C')
```

Comment: I would also suggest adding an exception handler for non-numeric inputs

Answer (score 0):

You should just use the conversion equations and do something a long the lines of what I have below.

```
temp = input("What is the temperature for tomorrow?\n")

def c2f():
    C_to_F = (temp × 9/5) + 32
def f2c():
    F_to_C = (temp - 32) × 5/9

F_or_C = input('Is your temperature in F or C?')

if F_or_C == F:
    f2c(temp)
    return(temp)

elif F_or_C == C:
    c2f(temp)
    return(temp)
```

Comment: Your functions should probably take an argument and `return` their results.